# Adjust geom_tile size to remove margin effect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize various random sampling methods that generate `(x,y)` pairs strictly inside the unit square `[0,1]x[0,1]`. My idea is to demonstrate uniformity properties by splitting the square into smaller squares and counting points within each of them. I store these counts in matrices of different sizes, e.g.

```
cells1 <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2), .Dim = c(16L, 16L))

cells2 <- structure(c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 
15, 16, 16), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

Naturally, I thought about `geom_tile` and my current code is as follows.

```
plot_step <- function(cells, filename = NULL) {
  library(ggplot2)
  library(reshape2)
  plot_data <- melt(cells, varnames = c("x", "y"))
  # transform from index to tile position
  plot_data$x <- (plot_data$x - 1) / max(plot_data$x - 1)
  plot_data$y <- (plot_data$y - 1) / max(plot_data$y - 1)
  ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, y, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red") +
    guides(fill = FALSE)
}

plot_step(cells1); plot_step(cells2)
```

[image]

[image]

It's almost what I want except for the minor issue. Ideally, the commented transformation and tile size in conjunction should produce an image that exactly covers the whole unit square, without hanging below zero or above unity.

I highlighted the desired margin with my excellent hand drawing skills for the second picture. I'm interested in a solution that would work universally for different sizes (`cells1` and `cells2`, for instance, hang out differently). It would probably be a slight data transformation or some adjustment for `geom_tile`, or maybe both.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to solve the margin issue: `+ scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))`. The use and behavior of `expand` is not well documented.

Comment: @bdemarest Maybe I did not explain this properly, but you can see what I wanted to fix in my answer. Your idea solves another similar issue, though I thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea by @Thierry, I was able to tweak axes in a following way:

```
plot_step <- function(cells, filename = NULL) {
  library(ggplot2)
  library(reshape2)
  plot_data <- melt(cells, varnames = c("x", "y"))
  n <- ncol(cells)
  # here's the adjustment
  br <- seq(1 - 0.5, n + 0.5, length = 5)
  lab <- seq(0, 1, length = 5)
  ggplot(plot_data, 
         aes(x, y, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
    guides(fill = FALSE) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = br, labels = lab) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = br, labels = lab) 
}
```

This works for all tile sizes (i.e. for `cells1` and `cells2` in my example). Here's the sample picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tiles are always places at their centroid. The solution would be to calculate a set of breaks and labels for each axis.

```
n.x <- length(unique(plot_data$x))
x.breaks <- seq(-nx / 2, 1 + nx/2, length = 5)
x.labels <- seq(0, 1, length = 5)
scale_x_continuous(breaks = x.breaks, labels = x.label)
```

You might want to add `coord_fixed()` as well. It will give you square tiles.

Comment: That expand trick does not affect the tile placement, it extends the plotting area, so it's seemingly unrelated. Am I missing something?

Comment: That `nx/2` step seems essential, but I cannot get the complete picture. Could you please add that trick to the code I provide so I can reproduce the desired image? My attempts lead to a more or less broken scale.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I was able to wrap it in a complete answer. The offset for `x.breaks` is a bit different, but you pointed at a right direction.